# Bridge channel to a sequence

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

This code is based on [Coroutines guide example: Fan-out](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#fan-out)

```
val inputProducer = produce<String>(CommonPool) {
    (0..inputArray.size).forEach {
        send(inputArray[it])
    }
}

val resultChannel = Channel<Result>(10)

repeat(threadCount) {
    launch(CommonPool) {
        inputProducer.consumeEach {
            resultChannel.send(getResultFromData(it))
        }
    }
}
```

What is the right way to create a `Sequence<Result>` that will provide results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the channel [`.iterator()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/-receive-channel/iterator.html) from the [`ReceiveChannel`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/-receive-channel/index.html) and then wrap that channel iterator into a `Sequence<T>`, implementing its normal `Iterator<T>` that blocks waiting for the result on each request:

```
fun <T> ReceiveChannel<T>.asSequence(context: CoroutineContext) =
    Sequence {
        val iterator = iterator()
        object : AbstractIterator<T>() {
            override fun computeNext() = runBlocking(context) {
                if (!iterator.hasNext())
                    done() else
                    setNext(iterator.next())
            }
        }
    }

val resultSequence = resultChannel.asSequence(CommonPool)
```

Comment: ChannelIterator does not extend Iterator

Comment: I think this may be out of date with 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in the end I came up with this rather unusual/convoluted solution:

```kotlin
fun Channel<T>.asSequence() : Sequence<T> {
    val itr = this.iterator()
    return sequence<Int> {
      while ( runBlocking {itr.hasNext()} ) yield( runBlocking<T> { itr.next() } )
    }
}
```

I do not think it is particular efficient (go with the one provided by @hotkey), but it has a certain appeal to me at least.